# deploying spring mvc web app to tomcat: classpath issue

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, classpath

I am developing a small web app using Spring MVC framework. Basically, the app provides web interface, where user can upload XML file and verify it against specific XSD file. I put my XSD file within  "src/main/webapp/XSDfoler". I put this folder into my Tomcat's classpath. (I am using Tomcat embedded into my Eclipse). In my code, in order to access my XSD file I simply used 
`ClassPathResource("myXSD.xsd");`

It works fine. Now, I created a .war file from my webapp and tried to deploy it to another standalone Tomcat. When trying to run it, it give NullPointer exception since it cannot locate "myXSD.xsd" file. So as I get it, I have to somehow include this file into classpath of this standalone Tomcat instance. I looked for some nice step by step tutorial or article explaining how to deploy webapp to a standalone Tomcat server after doing the development in IDE with embedded Tomcat. Could anyone please explain/help. Thanks!

Comment: in the war file is myXSD.xsd in classes folder?

Comment: you mean WEB-INF/classes ? No. It is in folder called "resources" which is in the root directory of .war

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ServletContext context = httServletRequest.getSession().getServletContext();
InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream("/XSDfoler/myXSD.xsd");
```

alternatively use `getResource()` instead of `getResourceAsStream()`